# Sending more then one mp4 attachment

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to create a bot where it sends song snippets, and I am wondering how I would go about sending more than one mp4 with a single command.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const { Client, MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Client();
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const { Menu } = require('discord.js-menu')
const EventEmitter = require('events');
```

````
    const { content, author, channel } = message
    if (author.bot) {
      return const embeds = {
[`${prefix}snip attention`]: {
    title: 'attention whore prod. fortune swan',
    attachmentPath: './ericsnip/attention_whore/attention.mp4',
[`${prefix}snip attention`]: {
        title: 'attention whore prod. fortune swan',
    attachmentPath: './ericsnip/attention_whore/attw.mp4',
  },
    }```
````

This is what I currently have, I tried to experiment by having the bot go through the file and to send every file that ends with .mp4

```
[`${prefix}snip hot seat`]: {
    title: 'hot seat prod. Alice Gas',
    attachmentPath: {const :musicFiles = fs.readdirSync('./ericsnip/hot_seat/').filter(file => file.endsWith(".mp4")),
}
  },
```

But now it doesn't even send anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome), and go to the [message options](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions), it tells you that you can provide an array of [file options](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/FileOptions) to the message, which means you can attach multiple files.

It is also outlined at the `<Channel>.send()` method in the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send).

For example, to send multiple attachments in a message you can do something like:

```js
<Channel>.send({
    files: [{
        name: "file name here",
        attachment: "./path/to/attachment"
    },
    {
        name: "file name here 2",
        attachment: "./path/to/attachment_2"
    }]
});
```

I suggest you try relying on the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) a little more in future. Once you get the hang of it, it is really easy to understand and find what you're looking for, and it gives you all your discord.js related answers.